# Explanation for console output

Tags: c, printf

I wrote this code to show inaccuracies when working with floating point numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    float sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0;
    double sum4 = 0, sum5 = 0, sum6 = 0;

    printf("%f + %f = $f\n", 0.1, 0.2, 0.1 + 0.2);
    printf("%f + %f = $f\n", 0.1, 0.3, 0.1 + 0.2);

    for (float i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
        sum1 = sum1 + (1 / i); 
    }

    for (double i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
        sum4 = sum4 + (1 / i);
    }

    for (float i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
        sum2 = sum2 + (1 / i);
    }

    for (double i = 1; i <= 100000; i++) {
        sum5 = sum5 + (1 / i);
    }

    for (float i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        sum3 = sum3 + (1 / i);
    }

    for (double i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        sum6 = sum6 + (1 / i);
    }

    printf("%f \t %lf \n%f \t %lf \n%f \t %lf \n", sum1, sum4, sum2, sum5, sum3, sum6);

    return 0;
}
```

Especially the part

```
printf("%f + %f = $f\n", 0.1, 0.2, 0.1 + 0.2);
printf("%f + %f = $f\n", 0.1, 0.3, 0.1 + 0.2);
```

puzzles me since the output after the equality sign is $f which I can't explain to myself. Can you explain the meaning of that to me?
Note: I searched on the internet and found nothing according to that.

Comment: `printf("%f + %f = $f\n", 0.1, 0.3, 0.1 + 0.2);`... Looks like a typo on that line, the last number should be `0.3`...

Comment: The only thing you will find on the internet is valid format specifiers and escape sequences. Of the the billions of perms of anything else, they are output verbatim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` is printing `$f`, literally, it doesn't recognize it as a valid specifier, there is nothing more to it, except for the fact that the `printf` specifier stream only takes 2 floats but you have 3 arguments, the third one won't be printed.

If you do want to print the third argument, which looking at your code, makes sense, then it's a typo, it shoud be `%f`.

As chqrlie points out below, you may also have hit the wrong key as `$` and `%` are probably side by side in your keyboard.

Comment: or it should just be `%f`... `$` and `%` are contiguous on the QWERTY keyboard, which would explain the typo.  Also note that `%f` and `%lf` are equivalent for `printf`.

Comment: @chqrlie good point.

Comment: This answer could have been summed up with a close vote